# How to get statistics by query in a range of dates

Tags: mysql-5.5, statistics

I have the following query:

```
select  SUBSTRING(VARIABLE_NAME, 5) as tipo_consulta, 
        VARIABLE_VALUE as numero_total_operaciones, 
        round(VARIABLE_VALUE / (    select VARIABLE_VALUE 
                                    from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
                                    where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status'), 2) as operaciones_por_segundo, 
        round(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((   select VARIABLE_VALUE 
                                    from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
                                    where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60))) as operaciones_por_minuto, 
        round(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((   select VARIABLE_VALUE 
                                    from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
                                    where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60*60))) as operaciones_por_hora, 
        round(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((   select VARIABLE_VALUE 
                                    from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
                                    where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60*60*24))) as operaciones_por_dia, 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sysdate()) - (   select VARIABLE_VALUE 
                                                            from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
                                                            where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status'))) inicio_periodo_reporte, 
        sysdate() as periodo_finalizacion_reporte, 
        TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((   select VARIABLE_VALUE 
                                    from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
                                    where VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status')),'%Hh %im') as duracion_periodo_reporte 
from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS 
where VARIABLE_NAME in ('Com_select', 'Com_delete', 'Com_update', 'Com_insert')
```

This query works very good but I need extract this stats by a range of dates, for example 12:30 at 14:00

This was the event scheduler I developed:

```
/*Modifico el delimitador para que el motor de la base de datos no termine con la ejecucion del evento*/
DELIMITER $$
/*Borro el evento programado si este ya existe dentro de la base de datos*/
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS evento_registra_queries$$
/*Creo el evento programado para registrar los eventos de la tabla de global_status a una tabla normal*/
CREATE EVENT evento_registra_queries
/*Indico la temporalidad en que se va a estar ejecutando este evento*/
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
/*Le indico que cada vez que complete la tarea lo siga preservando*/
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
/*Indico el comentario que va a tener mi evento programado*/
COMMENT 'Este evento programado ira registrando por minuto lo que acontezca en la tabla global_status'
DO
/*Comienza el cuerpo del evento programado*/
BEGIN
/*Inserto dentro de la tabla registra_eventos, los datos que se vayan presentando cada minuto*/
    INSERT INTO registra_eventos(tipo_consulta,total_operaciones,operaciones_segundo,operaciones_minuto,operaciones_hora,operaciones_dia,fecha_registro,hora_registro)
    SELECT SUBSTRING(VARIABLE_NAME, 5) AS tipo_consulta,
    VARIABLE_VALUE AS numero_total_operaciones,
    ROUND(VARIABLE_VALUE / ( SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status'), 2) as operaciones_por_segundo,
    ROUND(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60)))       as operaciones_por_minuto,
    ROUND(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60*60)))    as operaciones_por_hora,
    ROUND(VARIABLE_VALUE / ((SELECT VARIABLE_VALUE FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'Uptime_since_flush_status') / (60*60*24))) as operaciones_por_dia,
    CURDATE(),
    CURTIME()
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS WHERE VARIABLE_NAME IN('Com_select', 'Com_delete', 'Com_update', 'Com_insert');
/*Finaliza el cuerpo del evento programado*/
END$$
/*Modifico el delimitador al que esta por defecto*/
DELIMITER ;
```

and this is the table:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id                  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| tipo_consulta       | varchar(50)      | NO   |     |            |                |
| total_operaciones   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| operaciones_segundo | float(3,2)       | NO   |     | 0.00       |                |
| operaciones_minuto  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| operaciones_hora    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| operaciones_dia     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| fecha_registro      | date             | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| hora_registro       | time             | NO   |     | 00:00:00   |                |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: `information_schema.global_status` does NOT store the history. It contains current status variables values only. If you need "this stats by a range of dates, for example 12:30 at 14:00", then you must obtain the values at 12:30 and store, then do the same at 14:00, and calculate the difference. Of course, you may save this data into some static service table using event.

Comment: ok, I will use event but for example every minute I should run this event schedule to be recording every change in global_status to regular table. The only bad is an increase in IO activity

Comment: Increase IO? for to save 5 values into a table per minute? seriously? do not save ALL variables, save only those which you need really.

Comment: Thanks at lot @Akina for the comment, it works very good